# Getting Bad request for Connected App

Tags: lightning, rest-api, integration, apexrest

I am using Connected app to authorize the access token but I am getting bad request.

here is my code.

```
public static void test(){

    String clientId = 'REDACTED';
    String clientsecret = 'REDACTED';
    String username = 'stifel-rst@silverlinecrm.com.rstdev';
    String SecurityToken = 'REDACTED';
    String password = 's*******'+SecurityToken;
    String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientsecret+'&username='+username+'&password='+password;
    Http h= new Http();

    HttpRequest req= new HttpRequest();
    req.setBody(reqbody);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint('https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
    System.debug('request'+req.getBody());
    HttpResponse res=h.send(req);
    System.debug('res::'+res);
}
```

Getting output:

> Bad request 400 status code.

Comment: You really should not post your client id and secret values, and your security token, for the Internet to see. Consider replacing your Connected App and resetting your token. You've also exposed *someone*'s email address, and it's not clear that it's your own.

Comment: Is this a class testmethod?